# ajax adding "eval code" and "anonymous code" followed by ScriptResource.axd binary to Solution Explorer after Default.aspx

Tags: ajax, anonymous, scriptresource.axd

When I start debugging a website containing AJAX, hundreds of lines are added to my Solution Explorer following the Default.aspx... Solution Explorer looks like...
Script Documents
   Windows Internet Explorer
      Default.aspx

```
  eval code
  eval code
  eval code
```

(100's of lines of this with the following two lines mixed in)
      anonymous code
      anonymous code
(then...)
      ScriptResource.axd...Binary Code
      Scriptresource.axd...More Binary Code
(then MyProject)
d:/MyProject
      App_data
(etc.)

happens with a simple application like the one that follows...

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:calendarextender runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1"></asp:calendarextender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The application works fine, but the Solution Explorer is filling up with code?  When I stop debugging, the code is removed from Solution Explorer.

When I click on a line of this "eval code", it contains single lines of code like ...

Sys.IDisposable

or

Sys.Extended.UI.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.EditorToggleButton

Did not find anyone posting similar problems, but not sure how to formulate a question